# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError when trying to print a float field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just added a float field to my table and for some reason I keep getting this error when trying to show it on the view

`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError`

Does anyone know why? My view simply looks like

`%td= item.tax_rate`

Comment: See if this helps you out: http://www.tatvartha.com/2011/03/activerecordmissingattributeerror-missing-attribute-a-bug-or-a-features/

Comment: Thanks. but i found the problem. I forgot that I am doing a select in the controller....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why this is happening now. I am doing a select on the query and I did not select the field that I need.